# Can an eigenvector correspond to more than one matrix?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have matrices $B_i$ of the form:$B_i=A(C+C')+A'(C-C')$ such that $[A,A']\neq 0$, $[C,C']\neq 0$ and $[A,C]= 0$, where $[*,*]$ denotes the commutation operator.

$B_1$, $B_2$, etc., have eigen decompositions:

$B_1=c_{1i} \vec{c_{1i}}$ and 
$B_2=c_{2i} \vec{c_{2i}}$ and so on

Can a single $\vec{v}$ be an eigen vector of more than one $B_{i}$, s.t.:

$B_{1}\vec{v}=c_{1v}\vec{v}$ and $B_{2}\vec{v}=c_{2v}\vec{v}$ and so on?

If so, can one determine the maximum eigen value $c_{kv}$ out of all the eigenvalues associated with $\vec{v}$ for each of the $B_{i}$'s? And its corresponding matrix $B_k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

You can for example have matrices such that $B_i = (2-2^{1-i})B_1$, then $B_i$ will all have the same eigenvectors with eigenvalues $(2-2^{1-i})\lambda_{1;v}$. However we see that there is no maximal eigenvalue since the next $B_i$ always have larger eigenvalue for the corresponding vector.